# Transformation of any normal distribution into a standardized t-distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, normal-distribution, t-distribution

What will be the transformed Mean and transformed standard deviation if any normal distribution is transformed into a standardized t-distribution?

Does `t` force the mean and standard deviation to be 0 and 1 respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{N(0,1)}{\sqrt\frac{\chi_v^2}{v}}\sim t_v$$transformed mean will be 0 and transformed standard deviation will be $\sqrt\frac{v}{v-2}$ which is same as standard t-distribution's.

[Proof](http://www.statlect.com/ucdstu1.htm)