# Can we transform a t-distribution into a normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, t-distribution

We know that any normal distribution can be transformed into a t-distribution as shown in this post: [Transformation of any normal distribution into a standardized t-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149345/transformation-of-any-normal-distribution-into-a-standardized-t-distribution)

My question is can we transform a t-distribution into a normal distribution?

Comment: What sort of transformations do you consider? One can always transform a distribution to another distribution via the quantile and inverse quantile functions. The transformation that you link to is of a different kind and involves the division by another random variable (which is actually not really a transformation). So could you be more specific about this.

Comment: What you linked is not a transformation. What is your purpose?  It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is 
`<X>`, and you're wondering if `<Y>` is a good way to go 
about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As 
its written right now, the question appears to be an 
[XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Such questions (about transforming specific distributions to Normality) are FAQs: see [this site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=transform+normal+is%3Aquestion) for many variants and their answers.  After performing such a transformation you can follow it with [an arbitrary transformation of a Normal distribution to a Normal distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/200407/919). Conclusion: "this same construction gives many non-affine transformations that will map a variable X with any given continuous distribution into another variable that is identically distributed."